# cin.get() getting too much

Tags: c++, cin

I want a user to enter a char. I want to filter what they enter and take only the first char they type.

```
int main(){
    while (true){
        char n = readOption();
        cout << n << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


char readOption() {
    char input = '\0';
    while (input != '\n') {
        input = cin.get();
        if (isalpha(input)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return toupper(input);
}
```

If I enter `13@ jkjoi`, the console prints.

```
J
K
J
O
I
```

I only want it to print `J`. Why is it printing the other letters as well?

Comment: Is that comedy code? You know you have to terminate statements with semicolons in C++, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is printing all of the characters because (after you fix your semi-colon error) you loop forever:

```
while (true)
{
    char n = readOption();
    cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

This will call your read function over and over, forever!  Your read function loops until he gets an alpha character, so it ignores `"13@ "` and then grabs 1 character for each iteration of the `while (true)` loop.  If you want it to stop after reading the first alpha character, don't loop:

```
char n = readOption();
cout << n << std::endl;
```

**Updated**

With your comment, you can actually re-write your code entirely:

```
std::locale loc;
char c = '\0';
do
{
    // get a character with error checking
    while (!(std::cin >> c))
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (!std::isalpha(c, loc));
// ignore the rest of the input
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: How should I write the code then to allow new user input? If I get rid of the loop but just add a new n = readOption(); and a new cout, it won't ask for new user input, instead it behaves just like it does now.

Comment: @Chronicle I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to discard the rest of the line and ask the user for new input, add `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @Chronicle Are you wanting the user to *just* enter a single alpha-numeric character?  Do you want to keep or discard the rest of the input after that character?

Comment: @ZacHowland I want to discard the rest. What Praetorian said worked, although I am hoping to use something other than numeric_limits. If I can't find anything else, I'll just be using a large number.

Comment: @Chronicle In that case, there is no reason to use `std::cin.get()`, see the update.

Answer (score 2):

**Because you asked it to.**

You perform this in a loop, forever.

If you only want to do it once, then simply do it once. Remove your loops.